# Calculating average spending (amount spent/person) in a particular month mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, math, sum, division

I have three tables in my database with schema:

```
items (itemID: integer, description: string, price: integer)
orders (orderID: integer, itemID: integer, aID: integer, customerID: integer, date: date)
customers (customerID: integer, fName: string, lName: string)
```

I need to calculate the average amount of money spent by ALL customers in a given month (between 2013-03-01 and 2013-03-31) which is total amount spent/total no of customers, 
to do this I need to calculate the sum of the prices of all products purchased between those dates (using information from itemID in orders and price in items), I did this with this code:

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM items WHERE itemID IN( SELECT itemID FROM orders WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-03-01' AND '2013-03-31' )
```

But i am having trouble figuring out how to divide this number by total number of customers (which can be found by counting the number of customers on the customers table - the unique key is the customerID)

Can anyone help? 
thanks!

Comment: How do you know a customer didn't start after that month?

Comment: good question but i don't know.. this is for a given set of data from my school and i think we are to assume the set of customers is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery :

```
SELECT SUM(i.price)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers)
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN orders o ON i.itemID = o.itemID
                  AND o.date BETWEEN '2013-03-01' AND '2013-03-31'
WHERE o.itemID IS NOT NULL
```